Google Pay also as a payment gateway for future payments?
I want to save a token from Google Pay for future payments?
Is that possible? Or does I need using Stripe?
Do you know any Google api that can help me?
Answer from ChatGPT but maybe not updated?:

Role of Google Pay
•   Payment Data Provider: Google Pay allows users to select a payment method and provides you with a payment token.
•   Not a Payment Processor: Google Pay does not handle the authorization, capture, or settlement of payments. It doesn’t move funds from the customer’s account to your business account.

Role of Payment Gateways
•   Processing Payments: Payment gateways/processors handle the actual transaction, moving funds from the customer’s account to yours.
•   Tokenization and Security: They provide secure ways to handle payment data, including tokenization and storage for future transactions.
•   Compliance: They ensure transactions comply with financial regulations and standards (e.g., PCI DSS).



You need to use a payment service provider (like Stripe) for "future payments" with Google Pay. The flow then usually goes more or less like this:

You integrate Google Pay. Either trough the Google Pay APIs directly or by using one of your PSPs SDKs.
During an initial Google Pay transaction you "tell" the PSP that you need a token for future transactions.
In the response of the initial transaction your PSP returns this token.
Store this token (and potentially additional properties) in your DB for future payments.

